# Grammar for given language

Tags: grammar

I am given the language {w ∈ {a,b}∗| |w|a = |w|b + 1}. and am asked to find a grammar.
I have come up with the following:

```
    S->aSb | bSa | aAa | bBb | a
    A->bS
    B->?
```

and was wondering if this was correct, or if not why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific coding / implementation problem.

Comment: The OP asks for the correctness of the given answer, and that is not a good enough question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct, because it cannot generate the valid sentence:

```
baaab
```

which has one more `a` than `b`. It should be obvious that this sentence cannot be generated because every sentence generated by your language has different start and end characters.

**Edit** The edited question is also not correct because the productions:

```
S -> ... | aAa | a | ...
A -> bS
```

is equivalent to (by substituting the RHS of `A` for its use in `S`):

```
S -> ... | abSa | a | ...
```

which will match as follows:

```
S -> abSa -> abaa
```

Comment: I edited it, its still not complete but would that at least work for aba? And how could I implement B?

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Apalala: It is an answer to the question asked, which was "is this correct (no), or if not why (counterexample)". It is not an answer to the question: "What is the solution to my homework problem?", but that is not what was being asked.

Comment: @tyuip: Please don't change questions after they have been answered. It disconnects the answer from the question. In any event, your change isn't correct either because it will match, for example, `aaaaabaaaaaa`.